# python jarvis not running

Tags: python, visual-studio

I am having a little trouble coding Jarvis. Whenever I say `open youtube` it just won't open and even Wikipedia won't run. This is my code:

```py
import pyttsx3
import speech_recognition as sr
import datetime
import wikipedia
import webbrowser

engine = pyttsx3.init('sapi5')
voices = engine.getProperty('voices')
engine.setProperty('voice', voices[1].id)


def speak(audio):
    engine.say(audio)
    engine.runAndWait()

def wishMe():
    hour = int(datetime.datetime.now().hour)
    if hour>=0 and hour<12:
        speak('Good Morning Sir')
    elif hour>=12 and hour<18:
        speak('Good Afternoon sir')
    else:
        speak('Good Evening sir')    

        speak('I am Jarvis')   
def takeCommand():
    r = sr.Recognizer()
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        print('Listening...')
        r.pause_threshold = 1
        audio = r.listen(source)

    try:
        print('Recognizing...')
        query = r.recognize_google(audio, language='en')
        print(f"User said: {query}\n")

    except Exception as e:

        print('say that again pls sir')
        return "None"
    return query       


if __name__ == "__main__":
   wishMe()
   while True:
        query = takeCommand().lower()
   #executing task based on query


   if 'wikipedia' in query:
       speak('Searching wikipedia')
       query = query.replace("wikipedia", "")
       results = wikipedia.summary(query, sentences=2)
       speak("According to Wikipedia")
       speak(results)

   elif 'open YouTube' in query:
       webbrowser.open_new_tab("https:\\www.youtube.com")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `if` and `elif` down at the bottom are not in the `while True` loop.

Also, it should be `elif 'open youtube' in query`, since youre using `.lower()`.

Comment: there is a mistake in your elif statement, you put 'in query' in side of quotes

Answer (score 0):

Indentations are important... keep if and elif inside the while loop.

And ***'open YouTube'*** is ***wrong*** you should write all small letters, because, since you said .lower(), you are saying the system to take your commands in lowercase letters, so when you say "Open YouTube" it won't take your command so do write **'open youtube'**, it is **"correct"***